# Are there maintenance-mode for vue/cli app?

Tags: vuejs2, maintenance-mode

I wonder if for vue/cli / bootstrap-vue project/vue-router / "vue-resource" project
with laravel 6 as backend api there are some goods decisions/plugins like
maintenance-mode in laravel, with blocking all site with common message and posibility to leave access to some pages, like admin area ?

Thanks!

Comment: Have anybody any decision from prior expierence ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a decision on server in bacckend app run

```
php artisan down --message="Upgrading,,," --retry=60
```

and on client part to catch 503 error :

```
Vue.http.interceptors.push(function (request, next) {
    next(function (response) {
        if ( response.status === 503 ) {
           this.$router.push('/MaintenanceMessage') // maintenancePage
        }
```

...